# How does bash built-in test handle variable without quotes?

Tags: bash

I am aware then in case of bash `test` one needs to use quotes around variable:

```
$ var=; [ "$var" = 1 ] || echo 'variable var not set'
variable var not set
$ var=; [ $var = 1 ] || echo 'variable var not set'
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
variable var not set
$
```

However, why do I receive this "unary operator expected" error if I do not use quotes around variable? In other words, what does $var mean to test if it has no quotes?

Comment: Like any other regular command, `test` doesn't know if quotes were passed or not -- they're taken off by the shell during its process of assembling an argument list. The issue is that if you don't use quotes, `$var` could become zero argument, or more than one arguments, and predicting how `test` behaves in *those* cases is tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `script.sh`

```
var=
[ $var = 1 ] || echo 'variable var not set'
```

run it with `bash -x` - and get

```
+ var=
+ '[' = 1 ']'           #<--------- see this
script.sh: line 3: [: =: unary operator expected
+ echo 'variable var not set'
variable var not set
```

because the `$var` *is empty* (not set) into the test comes an empty string, what is lead to syntax error.

if do you  use the `[[` - bash extension like

```
var=
[[ $var = 1 ]] || echo 'variable var not set'
```

and again `bash -x`

```
+ var=
+ [[ '' = 1 ]]
+ echo 'variable var not set'
variable var not set
```

using `[[` instead of `[` gives you a bit more flexibility, but comers with a price. It is not portable, isn't defined in POSIX and so on...

Anyway, it **IS A GOOD PRACTICE** quote every variable. For example, if the variable will hold a filename with a space like: `file name.txt` - on the expansion without quotes you will get *two words* what is usually leads to error.

If you want know a bit deeper how bash works, when bash start evaluating your script doing the following:

1. parsing and lexical analysis
2. expansion

   1. brace expansion
   2. tidle expansion
   3. variable expansion
   4. artithmetic and other substitutions
   5. command substitution
   6. word splitting
   7. filename generation (globbing)
3. removing quotes

as you can see, the last one is `removing quotes`.

You need to understand too, when bash evaluating at the final stage everywhere you have `$variable` is got **replaced** (expanded) with the *variable content*. Therefore, when the variable is *empty* got replaced with the empty string and the expression

```
$var=
[ $var = 1 ]
```

is evaluated exactly as

```
[ = 1]
```

what is (of course) error.

Comment: It's worth noting that `[` is a command, and so the normal parsing rules for the following words (which are just arguments to the command) apply, while `[[` is a reserved keyword that introduces a conditional expression, for which special parsing rules (such as no word-splitting on the results of parameter expansions) apply.

Comment: Also, while indeed not part of POSIX sh, `[[` isn't entirely a bashism -- it comes from `ksh`, which has more (spiritual) derivatives than bash alone.

Comment: Thanks for such exhaustive explanation! When I use quotes around $var, then `test` command is executed like this: `'[' '' = 1 ']'`. If I do not use use quotes around $var, then `test` command is executed like this: `'[' = 1 ']'`. Latter command gives the "unary operator expected" error. So is it correct to say that in first example the $var is empty while in the second one it is missing altogether?

Comment: @Martin exactly - if the variable is empty, it is replaced with "nothing". If the nothing is inside a quotes, the result is an `""` empty string, so the test `[` can do a compare 1 with an empty string. Without quotes, the result is nothing - so - the result is syntax error...